# What's the name of this iphone control?

Tags: android, ios, mobile-application, iphone, smartphone

What's the name of this iphone control? It's like a slider/tab control:
[image]

Does it exist in android?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a **[segmented control](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/controls/segmented-controls/)**, from the Human Interface Guidelines (Apple)

For Android, you get a reference to Material Design. They have a **[toggle button](https://material.io/components/buttons#toggle-button)** .

Comment: Thank you for the answer.